# Pandas drop row based on year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to delete or drop some rows from the dataframe based on the `year` column. I'm utilizing the following code to do it...

```
usa_population.drop('year' == '1959-', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

I'm passing an expression hoping to target those rows. I have no error running this code, however, when I query the dataframe those rows still there...

```
usa_population[usa_population.year == '1959-']

        year    p_age   p_female    p_male      p_total
   2886 1959-   0       1996399.23  2064922.61  4061321.83
   2887 1959-   1       1998220.09  2070499.94  4068720.04
   2888 1959-   2       1966510.93  2034099.69  4000610.62
   2889 1959-   3       1921734.50  1985181.41  3906915.91
```

How can I drop this rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferred way of doing that is boolean indexing (just invert the condition):

```
usa_population = usa_population[usa_population['year'] != '1959-']
```

If you want to use drop, you need to pass the indices of the rows to be dropped. So from your selection of `usa_population[usa_population.year == '1959-']`, you can access the index attribute with `usa_population[usa_population.year == '1959-'].index`. If you pass this to the drop method, it will do the same thing:

```
usa_population.drop(usa_population[usa_population.year == '1959-'].index)
```